# How to read file contents of files in a directory and create copies into a new directory?

Tags: python, function, file

I have to complete this function according to these instructions, I have tried looping thru with for loop and ever the os.path approach but still cant figure it out? how can I Improve upon this?

> ```
> def copy_files():
> ```
>
> - Open each `.txt` file in the `datafiles` folder.
> - `datafiles` contain 10 `.txt` files with numbers separated by ','. Each file in `datafiles` is named `file00`, `file01`, `file0(+=1)`...
> - Read in the text and then write it back out to an identically named file in the `mydatafiles` sub-folder within the `myfiles` folder.
> - You have to achieve this by reading in the text from each file as a string and then writing it back out to the new file.
> - This function requires no error handling and has no return value.
> - When done, the `mydatafiles` folder will contain a copy of each file within the `datafiles` folder.

```
from shutil import copyfile

def copy_files():
    src_files = os.listdir('datafiles')
    for file_name in src_files:
        full_file_name = os.path.join('datafiles', file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
            copyfile(full_file_name, 'mydatafiles')
```

Alternative approach:

```
from shutil import copyfile

def copy_files():
    completeName = os.path.join('myfiles', "mydatafiles")
    new_file = " "
    for file in 'datafiles':
        new_file += file
    incompleteName = os.path.join('datafiles', new_file)
    with open(incompleteName,'r') as firstfile, open('completeName','a') as secondfile: 
        for line in firstfile:    
             # write content to second file 
             secondfile.write(line)
```

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

for `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)` destination must complete filename not directory, use `copy()` to use directory as destination

```
def copy_files():
    src_files = os.listdir('datafiles')
    for file_name in src_files:
        full_file_name = os.path.join('datafiles', file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
            targetFile = os.path.join('mydatafiles', file_name)
            copyfile(full_file_name, targetFile)
            # or
            # copy(full_file_name, 'mydatafiles')
```